# Is a wet tent a Faraday cage?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life

A Faraday cage should be of a material that is a good conductor.
While water is surely not as good as copper in that matter, it should be still a much better conductor than the air inside the tent.

So: If we got a wet tent: Is it a Faraday cage or isn't it?
Please explain why, or why not, especially the differences to a "normal" Faraday cage that might prevent the tent from being so.

Comment: The exact electrochemistry of why is beyond me, but you can already know the answer is "no" because a cell phone works inside of a wet tent, generally.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. I am quite sure I used my cell phone in my car as well....

Comment: Is a wet tent a safe place to be in a lightning storm? **No**. If you're going camping and lightning is a concern, seek appropriately qualified advice about what to do in a lightning storm.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty this was more about physics if the tent is really, really soaked wet. I am aware that there are better places. I am more interested in WHY this is NOT a real faraday cage.

Comment: @OleAlbers Yes, it's a good question, but some clear ground on safety matters is never amiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the answer is no, chiefly because, even if the wet sides of the tent actually did act as screening, the base/floor of the tent, often being dry, will still be exposing the occupants to ground strikes.

So, if you were lucky enough to survive the lighting discharge bring routed through the tent poles to ground, you would still be in danger.

[image]

Photo Credit: [Ground Strike](http://mrcc.isws.illinois.edu/living_wx/lightning/index.html)

You could also read this (anecdotal) story carried on the  BBC website.

> The whole tent was filled with smoke while smoke was also coming out of our mouths.
>   We were - to pardon the pun - in shock afterwards.
>   The force was just so strong. It felt as if we had travelled at high speed and slammed into an unmoveable object. The pain was extraordinary.
>   I had a burn mark on my shoulder which luckily has gone down thanks to a treatment of aloe vera.
>   I think it was because I was close to the tent poles and my body was slightly touching them. I think the current passed through me and through to the others. There were scorch marks all over the metal poles although luckily the tent managed to stay together.

[image: o]

[Damaged tent poles and wet tent fabric](http://mrcc.isws.illinois.edu/living_wx/lightning/index.html)

Comment: Those guys were definitely NOT happy campers!

Comment: @DavidWhite  I live in (constantly wet ) Ireland, there is nothing more dispiriting than looking out on a rainy morning in a soaking wet campsite. A lighting strike would be welcome :)